# Filter result from database where row is null

Tags: kotlin, sqlite

I want to display all rows from database where row at specified column is empty (data is not inserted). To do that, in my `onCreateLoader` I wrote following code:

```
   override fun onCreateLoader(p0: Int, p1: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
        val projection  = arrayOf(
            WalletEntry._ID,
            WalletEntry.KEY_TITLE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_MONEY,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_DATE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_EXPENSE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LAST_TRANSACTION_TITLE,
            WalletEntry.KEY_LOCALES,
            WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY
        )

        val selection = "${WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY} = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("")


        return applicationContext?.let { context ->
            CursorLoader(context,
                    WalletEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null)
        }!!
    }
```

Where I want to display all results where `WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY` has no signed value, is empty. I tried to specify selectionArgs as null but it neither worked. So, how am I suppose to write `selectionArgs` to display all results where given row is empty?

To make my situation more clear I'll provide an app target. I'm learning kotlin and decided to write something like "bank" application where you can add different wallets and specify currencies. If you add a new currency it's being instantly added to the database to the column `WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY`. Then I have a list containing all "wallets", in which after adding a new currency an empty extra wallet appears. To avoid that I want to filter results and display only those, which do not have value passed in `WalletEntry.CURRENCY` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for `NULL` values in that database column, I think you might be looking for:

```
val selection = "${WalletEntry.KEY_CURRENCY} IS NULL"
val selectionArgs = null
```

If the `selectionArgs` argument is not nullable, try setting it to `emptyArray<String>()`